# What is an "effeminate" opening act?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> China’s State broadcaster has issued an apology Sunday after parents
>   complained that an educational TV show instead exposed young viewers
>   to a barrage of long commercials and an "**effeminate**" opening act.

[Source](http://www.globaltimes.cn/content/1117934.shtml)

> ADJ If you describe a man or boy as effeminate, you think he behaves,
>   looks, or sounds like a woman or girl.

But how an opening act be effeminate?
opening act like opening a bottle?

Comment: It looks like a Chinese article which has been translated into English. In Chinese, we say 娘炮 for "effeminate".

Comment: The "opening act" is the first act (i.e., performance) of a show.  "Opening" means that it opens (i.e., starts) the show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This other quote from the article is necessary in understanding it:

> Among the complaints was disapproval for the program's opening musical act New F4, a quartet of male pop idols, who apparently weren't masculine enough for some on Sina Weibo.
>
> One of the comments, "If young people are effeminate, that means so is the country," was widely shared on Weibo.

"Effeminate" is a word with derogatory connotations describing men perceived as having too many stereotypically female characteristics, such as weakness, emotionality, and self-absorption.